# AWS BeansTalk expose docker port

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy an instance of [Docker Gogs image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/luxifer/gogs/) to AWS.
The environment and application starts fine, but the only visible port is 80, while I have "EXPOSE 3000" in my Docker file.
I added the following `Dockerrun.aws.json` to my git repo and deployed to AWS, but the port is still not visible.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "3000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Now I can never unsee "Beans Talk". Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Not sure how to resolve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying Docker to AWS Elastic Beanstalk -- how to forward port to host? (port binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317714/deploying-docker-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-how-to-forward-port-to-host-port)

Answer (score 4):

The container should expose port 3000. The container serves as the upstream for the nginx server running on the EC2 instance. Nginx server listens on port 80 and redirects traffic to the container listening 3000. Are you seeing this behavior? If not can you please share the output of docker ps on the instance?

Comment: I'm not that guy, but have same question. Yes, I see exactly same behavior as you mentioned, and I want to expose 3000 port, not 80.

Comment: + Anybody know, how we can implement it for config with AWSEBDockerrunVersion : 2 ?