# Deploying Docker to AWS Elastic Beanstalk -- how to forward port to host? (port binding)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, circleci

I have a project set up with CircleCI that I am using to [auto-deploy to Elastic Beanstalk](https://circleci.com/docs/docker). My EBS environment is a single container, auto-scaling, web environment. I am trying to run a service that listens on raw socket port 8080.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.4.2

...

EXPOSE 8080
```

My Dockerrun.aws.json.template:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "<bucket>",
    "Key": "<key>"
  },
  "Image": {
    "Name": "project/hello:<TAG>",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8080"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have made sure to expose port 8080 on the "role" assigned to my project environment.

I used the exact deployment script from the CircleCI tutorial linked above (except with changed names).

Within the EC2 instance that is running my EBS application, I can see that the Docker container has run successfully, except that Docker did not forward the exposed port to the host container. I have encountered this in the past when I ran `docker run ....` without the `-P` flag.

Here is an example session after SSH-ing into the machine:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
a036bb061aea        aws_beanstalk/staging-app:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'go run    3 days ago          Up 3 days           8080/tcp            boring_hoover
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ curl localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

What I expect to see is the `->8080` or whatever in the container that forwards it onto the host.

When I do `docker inspect` on my container, I also see that these two configurations are not what I want:

```
    "PortBindings": {},
    "PublishAllPorts": false,
```

How can I trigger a port binding in my application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I made a misunderstanding in how Docker's networking stack works. When a port is exposed but not published, it is still available to the local network interface through the Docker container's private IP address. You can obtain this IP address by checking `docker inspect <container>`.

Rather than doing `curl localhost:8080` I could do `curl <containerIP>:8080`.

In my EBS deploy, nginx was automatically setup to forward (HTTP) traffic from Port 80 to this internal private port as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a rails container (port 3000 using puma) by default **rails server** only binds **localhost** to the listening interface, I had to use **-b** option to bind **0.0.0.0** and that solved the problem.

In react I have no the same problem cause npm **[serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)** package binds all interfaces by default