# Docker expose not working elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a docker container of tinyproxy that I have put on EB. The container is running fine, Docker ps shows ports 8888/tcp, and logging into the container and doing netstat I see it waiting 0.0.0.0:8888 & :::8888.

But on my EB host I don't see any connection. Below is my dockerfile, I don't have a Dockerrun.aws.json for my single container as it seems not be be mandatory. Any ideas?

```
FROM alpine:3.7

MAINTAINER Daniel Middleton <monokal.io>

RUN apk add --no-cache \
bash \
tinyproxy

COPY run.sh /opt/docker-tinyproxy/run.sh

RUN chmod +x /opt/docker-tinyproxy/run.sh

EXPOSE 8888

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker-tinyproxy/run.sh","docker run -d --name='tinyproxy' -p 8888:8888 dannydirect/tinyproxy:latest ANY"]
```

#### Edit from comments below:

`docker ps -a` output is:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
cd352352ddb        ffe23df0902        "/opt/docker-tinypro…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          8888/tcp            zealous_volhard
```

and when accessing url from allowed ip in security group following output is given:

```
Not Implemented
Unknown method or unsupported protocol.

Generated by tinyproxy version 1.8.4.
```

Comment: Your security group allows connection to port 8888 of that particular eb host? Can you give full response of `docker ps -a` as well?

Comment: see output at, and security group allows all traffic from my ip at home. https://pastebin.com/jW2Yc3Hg

Comment: Also I forgot to mention when I point to this proxy I get this message, so it seems the expose is working?. https://pastebin.com/mK0i5zSa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying Docker to AWS Elastic Beanstalk -- how to forward port to host? (port binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317714/deploying-docker-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-how-to-forward-port-to-host-port)

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas?

- Judging from your output, you are reaching tinyproxy so your ports are properly exposed and utilitized.
- Now, what is strange is your entrypoint... `"/opt/docker-tinyproxy/run.sh"` seems like regular tinyproxy start, but... `"docker run -d --name='tinyproxy' -p 8888:8888 dannydirect/tinyproxy:latest ANY"` seems completely out of place. As far as I can tell from inspecting tinyproxy container, following should be set as entrypoint and cmd:

  ```
  "Cmd": [
      "ANY"
  ],
  "Entrypoint": [
      "/opt/docker-tinyproxy/run.sh"
  ]
  ```

  So you might want to adjust your entrypoint accordingly, since it basically expects `/opt/docker-tinyproxy/run.sh ANY` as starting point and gets something completely different.

Comment: Ok made changes and get same result. It shouldn't be this hard..lol

Comment: Did you try to setup manual proxy for your web browser and point it to your eb host with port 8888 and see if you can reach google? If you get `The proxy server is refusing connections` then it is not working correctly but If you can - then your tinyproxy is working and needs further configuring... Btw, why you use alpine image, install and copy run.sh, can't you use `dannydirect/tinyproxy:latest` directly?

Comment: tbh I have no idea, I was just following their dockerfile. I pointed browser but I get same page and error message.

Comment: even if you just start their docker as per documentation, you'lll get that page. This is proxy server, you need to configure network settings of your browser to use it or to configure it to display something else if browsed to it. It is up and running but with blank configuration...

Comment: its configured with ANY so I'm expecting it to server my url requests but it is not.

Comment: yes, yes, but did you try to set it as proxy in your browser? Since message you get is if you go to url of your proxy (not the same thing)...